# Combine Two Types of Paste in an Excel VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

My wish is to set the default paste in Excel as values only or match destination formatting. I know how to create a macro for each one individually, but xlPasteValues only works when you copy from a cell in a workbook, and match destination formatting doesn't (but it does work when copying from a webpage, which is what I want). My goal is to create a single VBA macro that combines both so I only have to use one command and regardless of whether I copied from a cell or webpage, it will paste without any source formatting.

Pseudo code:

```
Sub SuperPaste()
     if clipboard source is a cell (or vice versa, whatever is easier):
          Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
               :=False, Transpose:=False
     else:
          ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
               False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
(maybe some error handling)
End Sub
```

Comment: The closest method I can think of is to use `Application.CutCopyMode <> False` to determine if the clipboard contains an object or text. The expression is True when the Clipboard contains an Object (like a cell) which originates from the current Application (Excel). Other than that, you'll have to do some API to ask Windows what they've got in their clipboard, which is much more complicated and harder to do in VBA. If you know it's an object, you can do `xlPasteValues`, otherwise just paste normally.

Comment: @Toddleson: I've tried `Select Case Application.CutCopyMode`. It doesn't behave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following does what you're attempting to do:

```
Sub SuperPaste()
     
''' Clipboard source is a current-instance excel cut:
''' - only option is to paste all (or throw an error msg)
    If Application.CutCopyMode = xlCut Then
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        
''' Clipboard source is a current-instance excel copy:
''' - paste values only (keeps destination formats)
''' - am pasting to the activecell to avoid mis-matched source and destination selections
    ElseIf Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy Then
        ActiveWindow.ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            
''' Clipboard is empty: report to user
    ElseIf Application.ClipboardFormats(1) = -1 Then
        MsgBox "Nothing has been copied."

''' Clipboard source is another application (including another instance of excel):
''' - paste text (same as paste values for excel)
''' - still retains numbers (if tabbed or tabled apart) from word, html, another instance of excel, etc.
    Else: ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text"
    End If

End Sub
```

Notes:

1. You can do more sophisticated things by declaring Lib functions for working with the clipboard
2. However, the above works for 99.9% of the types of copies where you want to keep destination formats

EDIT: Added handling of an empty Clipboard

Comment: It throws `Run-time error '1004': PasteSpecial method of Worksheet class failed` unless it is text, i.e. it is never `xlCut` so it always throws the `xlCopy` error. Maybe it is version-related (I'm using `Win10 64bit Office 2019 64bit`): could you confirm that this works on your machine.

Comment: @VBasic2008: Interesting. I did test before posting (and all worked). I've now tested (all variations of cut/copy source) in both 365 (64-bit) and 2010 (32-bit) (don't have access to 2019 today). All works as intended in those two versions tested. That makes it less likely (though not impossible) to be version related. Perhaps the issue's a particular copy source? What are you copying from when it throws the error?

Comment: I'm just selecting a range and using `Ctrl+X` or `Ctrl+C` to 'let `CutCopyMode` do its thing'. Then I select another cell and run the sub and the error occurs. The same was happening while using a similar code I wrote.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much! I did a some light testing just now and it works when the source is another cell, a webpage, a PDF file, and another workbook. It's fantastic!! The only thing I don't understand is why undo doesn't work with any of the paste macros I've tried, this one included. Not a big deal at all, but it would be nice.

Comment: Glad to help :) An yeah, preserving the undo chain in vba (when you can't, when you can, and how to when you can) is whole subject in and of itself.

Comment: @VBasic2008 : I got around to testing this with 2019 systems (both 32-bt and 64-bit). Both worked as expected and the code performed as intended. So, with 356 (64), 2010 (32), 2019 (64 and 32) all behaving as correctly, it strongly suggests whatever you're seeing isn't version related, but rather something specific about your system.